# redirect on page by position

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem regarding on how to redirect page by thier respective postion after clicking log in. i have "employee" table in my database and  the ff fields in my "employee"  table are "e_fullname , e_position " my probem is that if im going to log in in the page it must be redirect on the page depending on the position of the employee. let say for example i logged in and my position is  a cashier so the page must be redirect to cashier.php and if im  admin  it must be redirect to admin.php. . .i tried searching different technique on how to solve this problem but seems not working with me. this is my code so far. this code is working but not on what i am looking for.any answer is accepted .thank you !

```
$login = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);


//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 || $login = "james") {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['username'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: user/auto.php?id=0");
        exit();
    }

    else {
header("location: index.php");


    }

}
```

Comment: `clean()` ? Never seen that before. Sounds like a function to me.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Sounds like a sanitization function to me.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I Google'd it, but strangely enough, I didn't find anything. Bizarro, I've never heard or seen it before. Only thing close that I could find was http://www.habboxforum.com/showthread.php?t=447005

Comment: @Fred-ii-: That's because it's private to the application.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ok thanks, that helped shed some light on the subject, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`header()` takes a string. Just replace the appropriate value for the position within the string.

```
header("Location: $pospage.php");
```